# How to use date range in window function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

How to use a date range using window function in SQL Server?

I have this table:

```
id   date        item
----------------------
123  07/01/2018  anf
123  31/12/2017  sh
123  01/01/2018  ab
123  12/03/2018  fhy
123  02/01/2018  fg
124  10/12/2017  ab
124  03/03/2017  sh
125  21/11/2017  ab
125  31/12/2017  sh
125  01/03/2017  ab
126  31/12/2017  ab
```

I want all the information of `ids` from the latest date to the previous `30 days`. My data has missing dates so that I cannot use over partition by rows
I need to use the similar logic of date range in window function, but it is not supported in SQL Server.

Comment: You can use a Calendar table to find dates between the current and 30 days back and then join that with the target table

Comment: but I have many missing dates in between and millions of  rows

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: @user123 a calendar table doesn't have missing dates. Use a left join with the target table to retrieve all rows that match the dates in the given range.

Comment: @user123 in any case, what is the expected result? You don't need a windowing function to retrieve rows in the last 30 days, you can use `dateadd(d,-30,getdate())`. Are you looking for a running count perhaps?

Comment: @user123 check the two answers. Both are valid given how vague the question is. Gordon's assumption makes more sense than mine, that you want a running count. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,date,GETDATE())<=30
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want all the information of ids from the latest date to the previous 30 days.

Your question is unclear on what you actually want.  If you mean the latest date in the data, then you can use:

```
select . . . 
from (select t.*, max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date > dateadd(day, -30, max_date);
```

Comment: Thanks It satisfies my requirement